# Write a Javascript function to print out the numbers 1-10 with each number printing at an interval of 1s

Tags: javascript, datetime, timeout, settimeout, setinterval

I have been given a challenge question to write a Javascript function that prints out the numbers 1-10, with each number printing at an interval of 1s. I must do this without using 'setInterval' or 'setTimeout'. Which makes sense since these functions are async and the loop will not pause and wait for the timeout interval to pass. So I have decided to create a pause function using Date. Unfortunately this is not working. Here is what I've got so far. I am not sure why it is not working. Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?

```
function pause(milliseconds) {
    var dt = new Date();
    while ( (new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
}
function printNumbers(){
    var i = 1;
    var temp = "";
    while(i<=10){
        temp += i + " ";
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = temp; 
        pause(1000); 
        i++;        
    }
}

printNumbers();
```

Comment: Why is it not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hm. I tested it. If you just log it in the console, it works. But if you try to update the dom, it waits until the javascript is finished.

Comment: And thats the same problem like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490780/dom-update-followed-by-a-big-loop-doesnt-render-in-time And you solve it with setTimeout...

Answer (score 1):

As long as some JS is running the browser won't be rendering the DOM, Other than that your code works. Just replace

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = temp;
```

with

```
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you Rozalex. Please see the comment that I made to Soumitra's post above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way in which you want to see your output. The current browsers behaviour is to block HTML renderings as soon as it sees a javascript block or script inclusion (unless otherwise, you choose to exclude it after rendering is finished).

Also unless you defer(using settimeout, promise etc) code all javascript will run in a single thread and will not allow anything to take over.

So you will not be just able to see the output on browsers as you intend to see. Run same code on Node and with the console it will run as expected.

Comment: Thank you Soumitra for the explanation. I'm still confused though. I'm sure I've seen an animation like this done before in a browser. What might be some other ways to achieve this effect? I am out of ideas.

Comment: There is a way to do this, I mean update the dom. What you can do is move this logic to service worker. Use postMessage to send messages to the main thread to update dom every one second.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers